# Number of stop words variation in libaries sklearn and nltk

Tags: scikit-learn, nltk

Is there a reason why there is a big variation in the number of stop words? I assumed that there would be a general agreement from English experts how many stop words there could be. And even with varying opinions, the difference wouldn't be `100+` words.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
print(f"sklearn stop words count = {len(ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS)}")
```

This gives

```
sklearn stop words count = 318
```

While from nltk

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk_stopwords = sorted(stopwords.words('english'))
print(f"nltk stop words count = {len(nltk_stopwords)}")
```

We have

```
nltk stop words count = 179
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> general agreement [on] stop words

No, the definition is fuzzy and situational.
We apply stop words according to the need.
Even in sklearn, you might choose to tack on
additional stop words for a given corpus
where you find them distracting,
or delete e.g. "meanwhile" if that's informative
in the Tonight Show transcripts you're working with.

The important characteristics of stop words are
that they're common and they're uninformative.
Both of those are somewhat subjective and use case dependent.
We filter them so we don't waste time computing statistics
on them which no one will care about, and so we don't
waste display space on word results that no one will care about.

The authors of those two packages had different needs and
arrived at different decisions. Use a package from another team and
you're likely to find it made another set of decisions.

---

Let's look at the difference.
I will focus on just the A's.

```
import re
from textwrap import wrap

starts_with_a = re.compile(r'^a')
words = sorted(filter(starts_with_a.search, ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS - set(nltk_stopwords)))
print("\n".join(wrap(" ".join(words), width=78)))


across afterwards almost alone along already also although always among
amongst amoungst amount another anyhow anyone anything anyway anywhere around
```

Looks like prepositions and function words, to me.
No pejoratives that would disturb sentiment analysis,
nothing descriptive that would inform a topic model.